# como evitar valores duplicados en la consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo una consulta para sacar los datos de la tbl_proyectos. Lo que sucede es que en esa tabla el valor del id_cliente se repiten en distintos datos de la tbl_proyectos, como podria hacer para evitar que se tomen esos datos que se repiten, esta la consulta que estoy realizando actualmente me muestra los resultaods incluyendo los duplicados

```
$sql = DB::select('SELECT p.id AS id_proyecto,
                                p.id_cliente AS id_cliente,
                                c.razon_social AS cliente,
                                c.id_estatus,
                                e.descripcion AS estatus,
                                p.id_empresa,
                                em.razon_social AS empresa    
                         FROM tbl_proyecto p,
                              tbl_cliente c,
                              tbl_division d,
                              tbl_empresa em,
                              tbl_estatus e
                         WHERE p.id_cliente = c.id
                         AND p.id_empresa = em.id
                         AND p.id_estatus = e.valor
                         AND e.tabla = "tbl_proyecto"
                         '.$sql_cliente.'
                         '.$sql_empresa.'
                         '.$sql_estatus.'
                         GROUP BY p.id,
                                  p.id_cliente,
                                  p.descripcion,
                                  c.razon_social,
                                  em.razon_social,
                                  e.descripcion
                         LIMIT '.$desde.', '.$paginar);
```

Comment: Ya probaste aplicando un agrupamiento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta consulta tienes un par de cosas mejorables:

a) Utilizas el producto cartesiano (combinas todos con todos) para después quedarte con los que realmente combinan mediante un `WHERE`. Esto se puede hacer de forma mucho más eficiente con un `t1 JOIN t1 ON t1.c1=t2.c2`

b) Agrupas por un montón de criterios diferentes, por eso te aparecen `id_cliente` duplicados

c) No haces uso de ninguna función de totales `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `SUM()`, `AVG()`, `GROUP_CONCAT()` o `COUNT()` que agreguen los datos de cada grupo. Lo que consigues así es que MySQL te muestres un único registro por cada grupo que formes, habitualmente el primero que se encuentra en la base de datos.

La cuestión a) únicamente afecta al rendimiento; la c) a qué resultado esperas ver de cada grupo; pero la que más me preocupa es la b), te explico:

Si modelas que cada cliente puede tener varios proyectos y agrupas por cliente y la descripción de cada proyecto, tendrás un grupo por cada proyecto de cada cliente. Deberías agrupar por cliente y ver cómo agrupas los proyectos de cada cliente, si los sumas, los cuentas o concatenas su descripción. Así sí tendrías una fila por cada cliente, sin lo que llamas duplicados, que realmente no lo son.

```
SELECT c.id AS id_cliente,
        c.razon_social AS cliente,
        c.id_estatus,
        GROUP_CONCAT(e.descripcion) AS estatus,
        COUNT(p.id_empresa)
 FROM tbl_proyecto p,
      tbl_cliente c,
      tbl_division d,
      tbl_empresa em,
      tbl_estatus e
 WHERE p.id_cliente = c.id
 AND p.id_empresa = em.id
 AND p.id_estatus = e.valor
 AND e.tabla = "tbl_proyecto"
 '.$sql_cliente.'
 '.$sql_empresa.'
 '.$sql_estatus.'
 GROUP BY c.id
 LIMIT '.$desde.', '.$paginar
```

Fíjate en que únicamente puedo mostrar tal cual datos de la tabla `tbl_cliente`, porque agrupo por un registro único de esa tabla, mientras que los de las otras tablas ya deben aparecer necesariamente agrupados. He quitado las empresas por si hubiera alguna cadinalidad 1:N. Si quieres que aparezcan, mejor agrúpalas también. No pasa nada por agrupar algo que no se duplica.

Espero haberte respondido. Cualquier duda, déjamela en los comentarios.